# Desing Problem with Single Axis Solar Tracking System

Tags: solar-cell, system, tracking

I'm second year Electrical-Electronical Engineering student (It's Electrical Engineering basically but naming issues I guess) and my knowledge about circuits is limited to capacitors, inductors, resistors, basic diodes element-wise and simple circuit analysis using KVL-KCL and Terminal Relations.

TL;DR: I have been getting circuit lessons for the past 2 months, so I am not that knowledgeable about circuits (not considering high school experince).

Anyways, let me describe my problem. Here's my desing so far:
[image: Single Axis Solar Tracking System Incomplete Design]

Edit: I forgot to connect DC Supplies to U4. Assume there are.

[image: Revised Design]

Notes: U6 detects higher of V2 or V3 and outputs a voltage to change the position of SPDT relay which in return activates Q1 or Q2 to by completing the connection between bases of Q1 or Q2. U5 detects if V1 is the highest or not. If not, SPST relay turns on. If V1 is the highest then SPST relay should disconnect the circuit rendering transistors as off. But the problem is if V1=Vhighest, comparator will behave unpreditibly. So for the time being I'm stuck here. I'll be analyzing the circuit as if U5 will work as I wanted then check if this schematic will do what I want. But I'm uploading revised desing before analysis to get feedback. Thanks for your help.

Let explain my design:

**1- Sensing Unit**

Positive DC voltage applied *stationary* LDR's used a light sensing units. Changing resistance values will create different voltage drops across LDR's thus voltage values will be used as inputs.

LDRs are near a point. They're angled wrt surface like this: \|/

**2-Control Unit**

a)*Decision Subunit*
This unit compares input voltages and gives highest input as output. This unit is incomplete and I'll be explaining what I want to and my question in a second.

b)*Function Subunit*
This unit generates a PWM wave that drives a PWM Servo Motor. As you can see this unit is also incomplete and I'll be asking about this too.

Now, my need:

I need to obtain 3 different Square waves each input. For this purpose I tried using transistor as swicthes. When base voltage meets a criteria it'll turn on, thus changing the duty cycle. (So I want 3 states: Q1-2:off, Q1:on Q2:off, Q1:off Q2:on) But I don't know how I can turn my Vhighest information to a controlling information for transistors' on/off states?

I thought that if I can compare this Vhighest value with V1, V2 and V3 and find out which one it equals to, then find my way from there but I don't know how I can do it, if this method even sounds plausible. So I need advice about how to complete the incomplete parts of my desing, basically.

Notes: If you need further information about project, I can give you this: 3 different PWMs are required for obtaining 3 different states from a motor. If V1 is the highest I need a specific PWM which indicates that light intensity at LDR1 is the highest and changes the angle of motor to a specific value. If V2 is highest then I need another specific PWM and the same for V3.

Also this circuit should completely be analog. Please feel free to inform me if my problem is not clear.

Another Note: The elements that can be used are limited with LDRs,LEDs, resistor, diodes, capacitor, inductors,op-amps, transistors and servo motor without encoders(don't know what that is)

More notes: Thanks to @Trevor, I have found out that my pulse generator is incorrect. I'll be changing that part of my desing in a day or two but please feel free to give advice until then.

Comment: Electronical???

Comment: At the time when this area opened as a subject to study, it didn't cover all electrical engineering topics of the time so they opened 2 different area as "electronical engineering" and "electrical engineering". Then when the economical status of the country allowed a single area to cover all topics, "electrical and electronical engineering" which is equivalent to "electrical engineering". As I said, naming issues.

Comment: Oh, and electrical engineering studied high voltage while electronics studied low voltage. Weird stuff, don't bother.

Comment: Something sounds off with your plan here. The signal you should be sending to the servo should be a pulse which defines the current position. If there is an offset in the sensors the position pulse should be extended or reduced in the appropriate direction.

Comment: Actually a servo motor may be the wrong choice for this application. A simple DC gear motor with limit switches or sensors is sufficient and a lot easier to set up.

Comment: I don't know if it's or I'm correct but the material given to us says that servo motor's angle depend on the duty cycle of the pulse sent.The LDRs used are at different angles near the same point.So the angle of the light incident changes resistance values of LDRs and thus changes voltage drop across them. The decision subunit compares these voltages (V1,V2,V3) with basic comparator op-amps then gives the highest of them which denoted as Vhighest.So I thought,if I can somehow use this voltage as a swicth to turn on and off transistors Q1 and Q2,I can obtain different pulses to drive the motor.

Comment: Unfortunately I have desing specification to meet, so I can't change that. I should add this to my question.

Comment: but you don't just want to go to a particular location, you want to adjust the width to point at the direction that balances the sensor inputs

Comment: Then shouldn't I desing a completely new circuit? I was thinking that I could use the voltages at the ends of LDRs as the deciding factor for a switch action to occur which then changes the duty cycle. But I should ask this question: Is it the pulse width that drives a PWM servo or duty cycle (namely, Pulse Width/Period)?

Comment: DEpends on the servo.. but typically just pulse width

Comment: My bad. I thought it was duty cycle. Then you're correct, I should change my pulse generator. I'll edit when I'm done with that part but should I keep my sensing unit as it is and try to achieve my current idea or should I go with your suggestion?

Comment: hmm.. are these sensors static? Or are they on the thing you are pointing at the sun?

Comment: Actually this circuit will be tested in a laboratory environment. Assistants will be pointling light sources at them. But nonetheless they're static and not moving though incident light intensity can change.

Comment: hmm.. ok that changes things a lot.. at least as far as what the sensor information means.

Comment: I suppose. I'm not trying the get the most of sunlight. There are 3 stationary LDRs with different angles. To be specific (angle is between surface and LDRs) at 30, 90 and 150 degrees. I will obtain informatin from them and my servo will position itself accordingly. Whichever has the highest intensity, let's say 30 degrees one, my servo will move to 30 degrees position.

Comment: What voltage are you running this at and do you have specs on the servo?

Comment: I didn't decide on servo yet. +-25VDC range. Square wave voltages depend on serve but I don't think it'll be higher than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my interpretation of what you need.

[image]

U1-U4 compare the LDR values to detect when the left or middle sensors are the maximums. Depending on the outputs of those the voltage divider with three pots is adjusted to generate a demand POSITION voltage. This demand is capacitivly filtered to produce a slower swing between demand locations and make the servo move more smoothly.

The 555 circuit generates a 20mS sawtooth waveform. This is compared with the POSITION voltage to generate the appropriate width servo pulses by U5.

The reset circuit beside the 555 is supposed to ensure all the capacitors have had time to settle before the servo pulses start being generated.

**CALIBRATION**

1. Monitor servo pulses with a scope and adjust the saw-tooth current with pot X4 to set the pulse period to approximately 20mS.
2. Illuminate the left sensor LDRL, or short it out, and adjust pot X7 to position the servo to the correct left position.
3. Illuminate the middle sensor LDRM, or short it out, and adjust pot X6 to position the servo to the correct centre position.
4. Illuminate the right sensor LDRR, or short it out, and adjust pot X5 to position the servo to the correct right position.

ADDITION

If you have to get rid of the 555, this may be your best bet.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer Trevor. Unfortunately, I don't think I can use NE555 to generate a square wave, I must design a square wave generator myself. Can I change the NE555 part of the circuit with a square wave generator like mine? Also, what are the purposes of C7, C9, C5 and C1?

Comment: Also R5 and R9. And how does Q1, Q2, Q7 and Q8 work? I'm trying to understand but I couldn't work it out.

Comment: @SamedYalçın its not a square wave, its a sawtooth generator, and yes there are op-amp circuits that can create sawtooth or triangle waveforms easily enough. Just google it. The Transistors you mentioned just short out the top pots in the appropriate sensors states which causes the position demand to be pulled higher. The extra two resistors make sure the base current is high enough since comparators do not source much (if any) current.

Comment: Obviously, if you change the saw-tooth you need to change the divider chain to match.

Comment: What I don't understand about trasistors is that what determines the base voltages of Q7 and Q8? If Q2 is on, how can I find Vb of Q7. Same goes for Q1-Q8 couple. As far as I know npns' are saturated if Vb>Vc and Ve and inverse of that for pnps (inverse of these conditions for cut-off state). Also I'm assuming capacitor are mostly used to eliminate any possible noises, am I right? And if light intensities are R>L>M, U2 outputs Vdd ans U4 outputs ground. Now what's the voltage at the end of R9. I'm assuming it would be 0 due to ground but I don't understand exactly why.

Comment: I've been comparing 555 with [this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-555saw.html) and I don't think I understand how yours work.

Comment: @SamedYalçın You are overthinking it, the NPNs are either cut-off or saturated, that means there is either current being drawn trhough the base of the PNPs or there is not. When there is, the PNPs are saturated since the base current > collector current. C1 & C5 are there to slow down the position demand so the servo does not try to violently fly back and forward. There are two of them to set the initial voltage at power on.

Comment: Ya that 555 circuit is a simple one that is more temperature and supply sensitive than the current mirror I used.

Comment: @SamedYalçın Re the missing state.. When Right is max, neither of the max circuits are active. Since you only have three states, one can be considered as the default if neither of the other two are true. In that case both PNPs are off. Note the divider has three different states. namely Q7 on, Q8 on, or neither on. The latter is Right sensor voltage  = biggest.

Comment: @SamedYalçın stepping out for a couple of hours...

Comment: That's a rather simplistic answer, unlike my nature, but I like it. I still have some questions but I want to take my time to see if I can answer them on my own. I'll be disturbing you if I can't anser them, I hope I'm not bothering you much. Thanks for the answers sor far!

Comment: Hi again Trevor. I've been trying to understand how the capacitor C4 charges. According to [this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-555saw.html) capacitor voltage changes linearly while charging meaning there's constant current passing through the capacitor but I don't understand how. So can you explain to me how the circuit to the right of ne555 works?

Comment: @SamedYalçın it is a classic PNP current mirror https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_mirror. In a nut-shell.. whatever current goes down the right leg is mirrored in the left leg. The current mirror is used everywhere, especially inside op-amps, and you should become familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. My final question will be this: How does the reset circuit work? I couldn't work it out either. After that I'll be marking your post as the answer. I need to become familiar with popular circuits as you said, if you can suggest me some sources I'll be grateful. After that I'll be marking your post as the answer.

Comment: @SamedYalçın on power up the voltage on C2 builds up slowly keeping Q6 and thus Q5 on for a while, pulling the RESET line low.  When the charge builds up enough... ~0.25S the transistors shut off and RESET is pulled high by R6. D1 is there to dump the charge on the cap when you turn off the power.

Comment: How do you come up with that in a day? Don't you need to analyze this mathematically at first?

Comment: @SamedYalçın experience mostly. That and knowing what is critical and what isn't.

Comment: So you used that kind of circuits before and you know how they behave and you simply just integrate them into NE555? Is NE555 considered and op-amp btw?

Comment: @SamedYalçın yup. 555 is more of a hybrid functional circuit. It was the simplest solution from the start, till you added the must use list. You can replace it with an opamp triangle wave generator easily enough though.

Comment: Okay then. Thanks for all the answers and effort Trevor. I seriously don't know where else would I learn all these information. Take care!

Comment: I see that you give importance to stability and practicality of the system. Can I ask why did yo use electrolytic capacitors, and AD795/LT1017? I only used 741.

Comment: @SamedYalçın LT1017 is a comparator not an op-amp. But I basically used the devices available out-of-the-box in LTSPICE. Caps do not have to be electrolytic, but larger values are more limited in technology and availability. Not sure why I showed them that way in the triangle wave generator, other than to highlight they are bigger caps.

Comment: I thought they were technically op-amp. Does it have to be LT1017 and not LT741, considering the fact that inputs from LDRs are constant and the wave generator generates a 20ms wave?

Comment: @SamedYalçın invertor is like an op-amp but not the same. For this you could use op-amps but make sure the low level really is low, 741 is not designed for single rail, and is crap. If you can find LM339 comparators those would be better.